# Serialize and Deserialize object contains Map type which do not wrapper with property name, such as Baidu Push Notification IOS Message

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to play with the Baidu Push Notification RESTFUL API, however, I failed to figure out how to serialize and deserialize IOS Message object by Jackson with annotation.

- Json Example of Target IOS Message

  ```
  {
      "aps": {  
           "alert":"Message From Baidu Cloud Push-Service",
           "sound":"",  //可选
            "badge":0,    //可选
      },
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":"value2"
  }
  ```

  "key1":"value1" and "key2":"value2" comes from a Map.
- My IosApsMessage object

  ```
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

  public class IosApsMessage {

      @JsonProperty("alert")
      private String alert;   //REQUIRED
      @JsonProperty("sound")
      private String sound;
      @JsonProperty("badge")
      private Integer badge;

      public String getAlert() {
          return alert;
      }
      public void setAlert(String alert) {
          this.alert = alert;
      }
      public String getSound() {
          return sound;
      }
      public void setSound(String sound) {
          this.sound = sound;
      }
      public Integer getBadge() {
          return badge;
      }
      public void setBadge(Integer badge) {
          this.badge = badge;
      }

  }

  import java.util.Map;
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

  public class IosNotificationMessage {

      @JsonProperty("aps")
      private IosApsMessage aps;
      @JsonProperty("custom_content")
      private Map<String, Object> customContent;

      public IosApsMessage getAps() {
          return aps;
      }
      public void setAps(IosApsMessage aps) {
          this.aps = aps;
      }
      public Map<String, Object> getCustomContent() {
          return customContent;
      }
      public void setCustomContent(Map<String, Object> customContent) {
          this.customContent = customContent;
      }
  }
  ```

My serialize result json

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "alert",
        "sound": "sound",
        "badge": 1
    },
    "custom_content": {
        "category": "freetrail",
        "type": "state-change",
        "status": "rescheduled"
    }
}
```

What I want :

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "alert",
        "sound": "sound",
        "badge": 1
    },
    "category": "freetrail",
    "type": "state-change",
    "status": "rescheduled"
}
```

**I don't want the custom_content to be displayed, but I want attribute in custom_content. how can I solve this problem?**

Comment: The actual serialize result is { "aps": { "alert": "alert", "sound": "sound", "badge": 1 }, "custom_content": { "category": "freetrail", "type": "state-change", "status": "rescheduled" } }; However, I want it to be like {"aps":{"alert":"alert","sound":"sound","badge":1},"category":"freetrail","type":"state-change","status":"rescheduled"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve the requested output through a custom serializer.  The details will follow. This solution has pros and cons:

Pros

1. It gets the required output
2. It allows total freedom in how you generate the output

Cons

1. It seems that implementing custom serilalizer overrides all other metadata of the target class. i.e. the custom serilalizer ignores annotations of `IosNotificationMessage` (for example, property names). so you have to supply all the info in the code.

Here is the custom serilalizer:

```
public static class IosNotificationMessageSerializer extends JsonSerializer<IosNotificationMessage>
{
    @Override
    public void serialize(IosNotificationMessage msg, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        // serialize IosApsMessage
        gen.writeObjectField("aps", msg.getAps());
        // serialize map entries sequentially, thus skipping map name
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> customContentEntry : msg.getCustomContent().entrySet()) {
            gen.writeObjectField(customContentEntry.getKey(), customContentEntry.getValue());
        }
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Here is the annotation that associates the custom serilalizer to the application class:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = IosNotificationMessageSerializer.class)
public class IosNotificationMessage {
...
```

Calling `new ObjectMapper().writeValue(...` in the usual manner produces:

```
{"aps":{"alert":"Message From Baidu Cloud Push-Service","sound":"","badge":0},"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```